# User leaves activity by going back

Tags: android, android-activity, focus

Im connected to a chat server which gives me messages i print out in a textview. This continues when the user leaves the application by pressing the home key etc etc. I would like to close all streams if the user goes back with the phones back button to the previous activity. Problem is that onStop() and onPause() are both called independent of if the Home key was pressed or the back key. Its just called when the activity loses focus or visibility, doesnt matter which way it happened.

How do i find out if the back key was pressed, and not home?

Comment: if you go back to the previous activity, doesn't onDestroy get called?

Comment: yeah i noticed, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own version of [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29). That way you'll know every time it's pressed and can do what ever you need to in that callback. So do something like this:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
  //Do the stuff you want to do


  //Then call the parent class version function to allow it to do any other stuff
  // that needs to happen as well.
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```